# Cocos2d iPhone: Rotate Sprite using Accelerometer

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, accelerometer

I'm trying to rotate a sprite using the accelerometer. when I tilt right, I want him to rotate slightly to the right, and when I tilt left, I want him to rotate slightly to the left...

Thanks in advance,
Reed

Answer (score 9):

Firs off - in your h file you need to make the following variables:

```
UIAccelerationValue accelerationX;
UIAccelerationValue accelerationY;
float currentRawReading;
float calibrationOffset;
```

Also ensure that your h file has:

```
@interface myViewName : UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate>
```

Then in your .m file just below your imports at the top put:

```
#define kFilteringFactor 0.05
CGFloat DegreesToRadians(CGFloat degrees) {return degrees * M_PI / 180;};
CGFloat RadiansToDegrees(CGFloat radians) {return radians * 180/M_PI;};
```

Then in your .m file on your viewDidLoad Function put:

```
UIAccelerometer *accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
accel.delegate = self;
accel.updateInterval = 1.0f/60.0f;
```

also add the following function to your .m file:

```
-(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration{

accelerationX = acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor + accelerationX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);
accelerationY = acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor + accelerationY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);

// keep the raw reading, to use during calibrations
currentRawReading = atan2(accelerationY, accelerationX);

float rotation = -RadiansToDegrees(currentRawReading);

targetView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-(DegreesToRadians(rotation)));
//targetView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(targetView.transform, -(rotation * 3)); //if you want easing
}
```

you will have to tweak it slightly based on what view or object you are targeting -- but thats pretty much it.

Hope this helps,

Michael

Comment: Note that this is for normal iOS apps. For cocos2d, all CCLayer objects conform to UIAccelerometerDelegate already and you just need to set node.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES and then create a accelerometer:DidAccelerate: method as usual. Refer to http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/tips%3ausing_accelerometer_for_sprite_movement However, you should probably still filter out the accelerometer readings as Michael O'Brien has shown. For more on that, refer to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be too difficult.  Just have somewhere in your code that handles the `UIAccelerometerDelegate` class and apply changes to your sprites based on the values you receive through parameters to the `– accelerometer:didAccelerate:` callback.

Apple docs for the delegate class are available at...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometerDelegate_Protocol/UIAccelerometerDelegate/UIAccelerometerDelegate.html

Answer (score 0):

In the delegate function of accelerometer just write the code -->>

```
float angleRadians = atanf((float)X_Position / (float)Y_Position);
float angleDegrees = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angleRadians);
float cocosAngle = 1 * angleDegrees;
sprite.rotation = cocosAngle;
```

and the sprite will get rotated to desired angle with changes in the values of X_position, Y_Position and angle.

Njoy.. :)